# How to resize toolbar in gVim?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, gvim

The problem is in the picture:

[image: gvim tooolbar]

I tried to

```
:set toolbariconsize=small
```

But it only changes icon size, but not the toolbar. It is staying huge. How to solve it?

I have fresh Debian 12 + KDE 5.27.5

Comment: For some reason, "Help" button not scaling properly. If I delete it via `:aunmenu ToolBar.Help `then toolbar comes to normal small size. Why is there problem with help button?

Comment: I think it's a problem with Breeze theme in KDE. If I change icons to Breeze dark, it doesn't show a half of icons. If I change theme to Adwaita then everything displays properly (even help button) and toolbar scales normally with icon size

Comment: Hello, please don't add bunch of comments with additional details. All of that should go into the question by editing it.